# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed when creating migration

Tags: laravel-5.8

`General error: 1005 Can't create table`eapi`.`#sql-12e8_2`(errno:
150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table`products`add constraint`products_user_id_foreign`foreign key (`user_id`) references`user`(`id`) on delete cascade)

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->text('details');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure that the table name is `user`? Shouldn't be `users` (plural)?

Comment: Yes the table name is user

Comment: Using MySQL? What's the column type of user.id?

Comment: The column type of user id is integer

Comment: You are defining your `user_id` column as unsignedBigInteger. The column type must be exactly the same to the foreign key work.

Comment: In the user table the ID is type of Bigincrements